# Php variable references

Tags: php

Why in this code is `$a` equal to 21? I am giving to `$b` the value of `$a` by reference, why is `$a` changing as well??

```
$a = '1';
$b = &$a;
$b = "2$b";
echo $a.", ".$b;
```

Comment: A downvote with no explanation does not help, I gladly accept the downvote if it has a comment :-)

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php
"References in PHP are a means to access the same variable content by different names. They are not like C pointers; for instance, you cannot perform pointer arithmetic using them, they are not actual memory addresses, and so on"

So setting $b as a reference to $a, is not setting the value but the variable context. So this is the content of variable a should be the same as variable b.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you define the variables with single or double quotes (both are ok)
That's how Php knows you mean a string

Regarding the reference - the meaning of reference, is that $b **points** to $a, so its not really a variable

and lastly, this: `$b = "2$b";` is basically string concatanation

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple explanation

```
$a = '1';
$b = &$a; // Sets $b to a reference to $a


echo $b."<br>"; // $b value is still one

$b = "2$b"; // here u write "2 and $b = 1" which means b = 21 and also Sets $a to 21

echo $a.", ".$b;
```

So your output is 21,21 hope you understand